# Number of solutions to congruence

Tags: number-theory

Find number of solutions to congrunce
$$x^2\equiv -2 \pmod{118}.$$

After dividing by $2$, we get $\frac{x^2}2\equiv -1\pmod{59}$. I know how to show that solution exists, but I could use some hints with proving that there are exactly 2 solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
x^2\equiv -2\pmod {118}&\iff 2y^2=2(\frac x2)^2\equiv-1\pmod {59}\\
&\iff y^2\equiv-30\equiv 29\pmod{59}
\end{align}
$$
Now observe that $29$ is a quadratic residue modulo $59$, hence the congruence has exactly two zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,
$$\begin{align} x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod{118} & \iff x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod 2\\&\phantom{\iff\ }x^2 \equiv -2\pmod{59}\\&\iff x\phantom{^2} \equiv \phantom -0\pmod 2\\ &\phantom{\iff\ }x^2 \equiv -2\pmod{59}\end{align}$$
Since $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $59$, it follows by the Chinese remainder theorem that there are exactly two solutions modulo $59$.

This method has the advantage that you don't have to calculate the inverse of $2$ modulo $59$.

Comment: Calculating $\large 2^{-1}$:$\quad$ Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than or equal to $3$.If $x = \frac{n+1}{2}$ then $2x \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.